# Does a full retail Windows 8 license grant me the right to install Windows 7 instead?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, upgrade, license

If I buy a full retail Windows 8 license am I granted the right to install a down-level version of Windows, specifically Windows 7, *instead*?  Just to be clear: I buy a full retail Windows 8 license - full version (not upgrade) and retail, not OEM.  But rather than installing Windows 8, I want to run Windows 7.  Is this allowed?

Comment: No, not allowed. Why would you expect the license for product A to be valid for product B?

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2015107/downgrading-from-windows-8-to-7-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: In addition to the comment above (in which I say it's not allowed), there are a few exceptions: http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=sLMLnUlmfw8

Comment: @WoLpH: Because the world ought to make sense, most of the time.  Alas, not this time.

Comment: @WoLpH - If I expected this to be the case I would have said something like "How come I can't run Windows 7 with a Windows 8 license?".  I just asked the question, which implies I did not know the answer.  And by the way, if it did turn out the answer was yes then I wouldn't be *too* shocked; I've had bigger surprises in life.  Robert Harvey's second comment says it well.

Comment: @Howiecamp: fair enough :) For a company like Microsoft however there is very little incentive to allow this. I follow your rationale though, I had the same when I got a laptop with Windows Vista some time ago... would have preferred XP instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Downgrade rights (which is what I assume you're thinking of) only applied to the Vista/XP era.

If you want to buy a license for Windows 7, there is nothing stopping you from purchasing an OEM license, or buying it outright from an online retailer.

Unless you buy an OEM license of Windows 8, which more information is available here.

http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=dVb0lSch56Y

Comment: not being a dick, but the QA said `I buy a full retail Windows 8 license - full version (not upgrade) and retail, not OEM. `

Comment: @Robert Harvey - OEM licenses are locked to the original hardware though.

Comment: @Znau: If the OP bought the System Builder version (there's no full retail version like for previous versions of Windows), then that *is* the OEM version.

Comment: @Howiecamp: No, if you bought the System Builder version for personal usage then the Personal Use License applies to you, and the license *can* be transferred.

Comment: @Howiecamp - The only OEM licenses that can be transfered are licenses sold by one of the major OEMs.  The Windows 8 System Builder license purchase by a non-OEM converts to a Personal Use license as Karan points out.